# UISearchBar cancel button not styled if displayed before viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I'm setting the cancel button's tint like so:

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance].tintColor = [UIColor highlightedTextColor];
```

And it works well if the cancel button is shown after or during `viewDidAppear` e.g. if Cancel is displayed when the search bar receives focus:

[image: Cancel button properly styled]

However if this is performed before, e.g. in viewDidLoad or even in viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Then the result isn't as nice:

[image: Cancel not styled]

The text is actually there, though only a very faint shadow can be detected with the Color Meter.
Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution?
The best one I could find is to show the cancel button in the `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Have you tried to put it in the didLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it works fine, I create UISearchBar inside a UIView.
The viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, 44.0f)];
    _searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    //_searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    [_searchBar sizeToFit];
    [_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchBar.barTintColor = color;
    _searchBar.tintColor = color;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                              [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              nil]
                                                                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _barWrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
    [_barWrapper addSubview:_searchBar];
    _barWrapper.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
}
```

In viewWillAppear I put the barWrapper in the navigationbar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_barWrapper];
    [_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

To finalize, in viewWillDisappear I remove the barWrapper from navigation bar.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [_barWrapper removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works for you because you're also calling `[_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];`. Otherwise the cancel button looks like it's disabled though it isn't (can be clicked and the proper methods are called).

Comment: No. I can remove the becomeFirstResponder and the layout stays the same. I only use the becomeFirstResponder to put the focus on the searchbar.
The color of the cancel button is defined in the `UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn`

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the time you took to respond. This time I actually copy/pasted your code and ran it. What I was able to dig down to is that the `tintColor` isn't working properly for `UIBarButtonItem`, which I guess is what I deserve since it doesn't have the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` annotation. However the code you wrote contains a few deprecated definitions. Refactor that to use `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the deprecated definitions. I was using deployment target 7.0. I update my answer, now it has no warnings for deployment target 9.2.